# Deleting an object from array based on a condition

Tags: json, jq

```
{
   "name": "ford",
   "availableVersions": [
      {
         "version": 111,
         "count": 3
      },
      {
         "version": 122,
         "count": 2
      },
      {
         "version": 133,
         "count": 3
      }
                          ],
       "RealVersion": 133


}
{
   "name": "bmw",
   "availableVersions": [
     {
         "version": 144,
         "count": 1
     },
     {
      "version": 155,
      "count": 3
     }                  ],
     "RealVersion": 120

}
```

I have this demo.json file now `if (count == 3)`. I want to delete the key value pair of count and the respective version. So my output should be like. I am using jq for parsing the json file

OUTPUT-

```
{
   "name": "ford",
   "availableVersions": [
      {
         "version": 122,
         "count": 2
      }
                          ],
       "RealVersion": 133


}
{
   "name": "bmw",
   "availableVersions": [
     {
         "version": 144,
         "count": 1
     }                  ],
     "RealVersion": 120

}
```

`cat demo1 | jq .availableVersions[] | jq 'select(.count == 3)'`

I am using this command which will select count and respective version but I am not sure how to delete it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It's not optimal or I'd add it as an answer, but `.availableVersions |= map(if .count == 3 then . else empty end)` does the job, as does `.availableVersions |= [.[] | select(.count != 3)]`.

Answer (score 4):

Just remap `availableVersions` selecting objects whose `count` is not 3.

```
.availableVersions |= map(select(.count != 3))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VRsxCPOxjz)</sup>